# Проверка при инициализация объекта класса

Tags: c++, ооп

Необходимо создать класс "цветная точка". Для точки задаются координаты и цвет, цвет описывается с помощью трёх составляющих(красный, зелёный, синий). При инициализации объекта необходимо выполнять проверку допустимости значений(например значения цвета должны находиться в диапазоне [0,255]). Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно организовать проверку значений, проверять в конструкторе или создать для этого отдельный метод.
Например:

```
class Dot
{
private:
    double x;
    double y;
    int R;
    int G;
    int B;
public:
    Dot(double X, double Y, int red, int green, int blue)
    {
        x = X;
        y = Y;
        if ((red >= 0 && red <= 255) && (green >= 0 && green <= 255) && (blue >= 0 && blue <= 255))
        {
            R = red;
            G = green;
            B = blue;
        }
        else {}
    }
};
```

Что делать, если входные данные для цвета введены не верно?

Comment: Два основных варианта: выбросить исключение (хороший вариант), либо напечатать сообщение об ошибке и завершить программу (не такой хороший вариант).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat спасибо. Но у меня ещё вопрос, ведь конструктор нужен для инициализации полей объекта класса. Соответственно будет ли правильным выводить сообщение об ошибке в конструкторе?  
Например:  
else { cout << "Недопустимые значения"; }  
Или это можно сделать более правильно?

Comment: *"будет ли правильным выводить сообщение об ошибке в конструкторе"* Обычно предпочитают исключения, потому что их можно при необходимости поймать и обработать, вместо того, чтобы позволять им завершать программу. Но если вы уверены, что вам это никогда не понадобится, или вы не умеете/не хотите работать с исключениями, то я не вижу ничего плохого в выводе сообщения ошибке.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat мне не нужно работать с исключениями. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Информация для размышления:  заданный  диапазон  соответствует диапазону типа unsigned char.   При других значениях происходит урезание

Answer (score 1):

Как ещё один вариант кроме тех что в комментариях, это при выходе за границы значений цветов устанавливать граничные значения, сопутствуя это соответствующим предупреждающим сообщением.

```
class Dot
{
private:
    double x;
    double y;
    int R;
    int G;
    int B;
public:
    int validate_col_comp(int c, int min, int max)
    {
        if (c < min) {
            std::cerr << "the color value is less than " << min << ", it will default to " << min << '\n'; 
            return min;
        }        
        if (c > max) {
            std::cerr << "the color value is grater than " << max << ", it will default to " << max << '\n';
            return max;
        }
        return c;
    }

    Dot(double X, double Y, int red, int green, int blue)
    {
        x = X;
        y = Y;    
        R = validate_col_comp(red,   0, 255);  
        G = validate_col_comp(green, 0, 255);
        B = validate_col_comp(blue,  0, 255);
    }
};
```

Comment: Уж либо надо в `validate_col_comp` печатать честные значения `min` и `max`, либо захардкодить `0` и `255` и в сообщениях, и в проверках.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat что значит "честные значения" !? чем те значения которые передаются этой функции "не честны" ?

Comment: Судя по правке, вопрос отпал? :)

Answer (score 0):

Зависит, конечно, от предметной области и уровня сложности программы. Разрабатывая что-то подобное, я выделил бы "цвет" отдельным классом, как это сделано, например, в Qt ([QColor](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcolor.html)). Поэтому в простейшем варианте пример получится примерно таким:

```
class Color 
{
public:
    Color() : 
        r(0),
        g(0),
        b(0)
    {
    }

    Color(int r, int g, int b)
    {
        setColor(r, g, b);
    }

    Color(const Color& right)
    {
        setColor(right.r, right.g, right.b);
    }

    Color& operator=(const Color& right)
    {
        // operator= implementation
    }


    bool setColor(int r, int g, int b)
    {
        if (isValidColorValue(r) || isValidColorValue(g) || isValidColorValue(b)) {
            cout << "invalid value to set color: " 
                 << r << " " << g << " " << b << endl;
            return false;
        }

        this->r = r;
        this->g = g;
        this->b = b;

        return true;
    }


private:
    bool isValidColorValue(int val) const 
    {
        return (0 <= val) && (val <= 255);
    }

    int r;
    int g;
    int b;
};
```

Далее Вы можете использовать его у себя (я позволил себе поменять местами блоки `public` и `private`, т.к. ощущаю более удобным сначала видеть доступные извне методы):

```
class Dot
{
public:
    Dot(double X, double Y, const Color& color)
    {
        x = X;
        y = Y;

        this->color = color;  
    }

private:
    double x;
    double y;

    Color color;
};
```

Что мы получаем?

1. Соблюдение принципа [SRP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8). Мы не смешиваем манипуляции с цветом с методами, отвечающими за поведение точки.

Остальные пункты явно и не очень следуют из п.1.

2. При появлении необходимости реализации других сущностей, обладающих цветом (линий, квадратов, окружностей и др.) мы не вынуждены заново колдовать с переменными `int r`, `int g`, `int b` и как-то их проверять... ну или дублировать код и класса `Dot`.
3. Ощутимое упрощение кода в классе `Dot`.
4. Нет необходимости повсеместно проверять параметры `r`, `g`, `b`, т.к. эта проверка уже осуществляется, причем осуществляется в одном месте.
5. Добавление новых методов (например, вывода представления цвета, конвертации в другие цветовые модели) повлечет за собой изменение только класса `Color`.

Примеры новых методов из п.5.

```
// return the "#00ff00" color representation 
string Color::toHex() const;

// return the "rgb(0, 255, 0)" color representation 
string Color::toRgb() const;

// return the "rgba(0, 255, 0, 0)" color representation 
string Color::toRgba() const;
```

P.S. я бы все таки использовал исключения, но при использовании в конструкторе ими нужно аккуратно пользоваться.